# Reference request: Straight lines on $\mathbb{R}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}^{2}$

Tags: geometry, reference-request

Can anyone give me a book recommendations about geometry on the surface of a torus ($\mathbb{R}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ specifically)? I'm doing a project on straight lines and when they form loops. I haven't been able to find anything specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the reference request, but to the question you want answered: Lines in the plane $\Bbb R^2$ form loops in the quotient space torus exactly when their slope is rational (or vertical). This you can see by taking two distinct points on the line in the plane that becomes the same point on the torus, and use those two to calculate the slope. Since the difference between the coordinates of the two points necessarily must be integers (by definition of "becoming the same point on the torus), the slope is a ratio of two integers and therefore rational.

For the other direction, if you have a line with rational slope, say $\frac mn$ then a difference in $x$ of $n$ makes a difference in $y$ of $n$. This means that in the quotient space it loops back on itself.

Also note that a line of slope $\frac mn$ with $m,n$ coprime, gives rise to the $(m,n)$ torus knot if the torus is embedded the standard way in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help me. I have something of a proof of the fact that only lines with slopes that are rational multiples of the dimensions of the tori divided by each-other. But i want to confirm that the equations im working are correct. It also would be useful to have a bibliograhpy.